# Simple Content Filter for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Im making a very simple content filter for wordpress. Basically prevents a post being created if the post contains any of the words from a set array. The filter does not need to inform the user of the mis-post. Just needs to stop the post being saved in the db, so far I have this:
    function thefilter($content){

```
$searchfilter = array(
    '#cure-plus.org#',
    '#porn#',
    '#escort#',
    '#no prescription#',
    '#Prescription#'
);

$count=0;
foreach($searchfilter as $filter){

    preg_match_all( $filter, $content, $pics );

    $count += count($pics[0]);
}

if ( $count > 0 ) {
   return 'This post has been deleted';
}
}

add_filter('content_save_pre','thefilter');
```

That all works and I can delete the post once it exists, but I would prefer it never made it that far.

Thanks :)

Comment: Ask a _real question_ and explain why this isn’t good enough. Note that a post ID is created the moment the edit screen is called – _before_ any word has been written.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the post from being saved, you could easily just kill PHP, or redirect somewhere.

```
if ( $count > 0 )
    die('You just got caught in our spam filter.');

return $content;
```

or

```
if ( $count > 0 )
    header( 'Location: http://disney.com' );
    die('You just got caught in our spam filter.');

return $content;
```

Make sure to kill PHP even if you redirect, to make sure that execution stops before the database write.

Also remember to return the original content to the filter if the post is clean.